# how to associate id with table row delete button in backbone

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js below is my code all I need is syntax/code required in backbone.js to produce unique id in every row of my table so that when delete gets pressed I delete that specific row from the table.

```
$(function(){

    var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        id: 0,
        name: 'default name',
        age: 100
    });

    var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Person
      });

    var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#personEL'),

        events: 
        {
            "click #login-btn" : "loginClick"
        },
        loginClick: function()
        {
          var name = $('#name').val();
          var age = $('#age').val();
          var newPerson = new Person({id: 1,name: name, age : age});          

          this.personCollection.add(newPerson);          
          var showit = new zview({model: newPerson});

        },
        initialize: function(){
         this.personCollection = new PersonCollection();

           this.render(); 
        },

        render: function()
        {
                var template = _.template( $("#personInputTemplate").html(), {} );
        this.el.html(template);
                return this;
        }
    });



     zview = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#personTable'),
        events:{
            'click #delete' : 'deleteItem'
        },
       initialize: function()
       {

        this.render();   
        return this;
       }
       ,
       render: function()
       {
           var template = _.template( $('#personDisplayTemplate').html(), this.model.toJSON() );
           console.log(template);
           $(this.el).append(template);
       }
       ,
       deleteItem: function()
       {
           console.log('delete');
       }
    });


var persons = new PersonView();

  });
```

html:

```
<body>




<script type="text/template" id="personInputTemplate">
    <p>Person Name<input type="text" id="name" /></p>
    <p>Person Age<input type="text" id="age" /></p>        
    <p><button id="login-btn">Save</button></p>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="personDisplayTemplate">
            <tr>
                 <td><span><%= name ? name : '' %></span></td>
                 <td><span><%= age ? age : '' %></span></td>

                 <td><a href="#" id="<%= id ? id : '' %>" class="delete"> Delete</a> </label></td>

            </tr>
</script>


<div id ="personEL"></div>
<div id="showPerson"></div>
 <div id="display">
        <table id="personTable">

        </table>
    </div>
```

Any help, advise, code is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to mess around with `id`s for this. Your event handlers get passed an event object and that has a `target` property and, for a click event, the `target` will be the DOM element that was clicked. Something like this should do the trick:

```
deleteItem: function(ev) {
    var $tr = $(ev.target).closest('tr');
    // Now $tr is the jQuery object for the <tr> containing the .delete
    // element that was clicked.
    $tr.remove();
}
```

Also, your template (correctly) uses `class="delete"` for the delete link but your event is bound to the element with `id="delete"`; you'll want to fix your `events` as well:

```
events: {
    'click .delete': 'deleteItem'
}
```

Furthermore, you have a stray `</label>` in your delete link and you can probably drop the `id` attribute altogether; just this should be fine:

```
<td><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></td>
```

If you do need the `id`s then I'd use a data attribute on the `<tr>`:

```
<tr data-id="<%= id ? id : '' %>">
```

and then you could use `$tr.data('id')` to access it. Attaching it to the `<tr>` makes it easy to find from anywhere within the row and using a data attribute avoids duplicating HTML `id` attributes and ending up with invalid HTML. The `id` values should come from the server as that's were they should be defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for best answer . But i still need the id so that the record gets deleted from the server eventually as well. how would i achieve it?

Comment: @Mian: I'd use a data attribute on the row, please see my update.